# Async loaded config data for reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, refluxjs

I'm trying to load a config.json file that contains properties that should be used as constants throughout the whole application.

I have a `config.jsx` as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

var config = {
  init(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    let obj = this;
    $.get("/app/config/config.json").then(function(response) {
        obj.ApiBaseUrl = response.ApiBaseUrl;
        deferred.resolve();
      }, function(errorResponse) {
        deferred.reject();
      });
    return deferred.promise();
  },
  ApiBaseUrl: null
}

export default config;
```

I then load the data and setup the config before the application is loaded as seen in `app.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import Config from './config';

Config.init().then(function(resp){
  Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, Handler => React.render(<Handler />, document.body));  
}, function (err){

});
```

So after `Config.init()`, we can access the loaded data at `Config.ApiBaseUrl`. If we import the config in another file, we lose this data such as in `home.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Config from '../config';

Config.ApiBaseUrl; // This is null.
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

How do I write my config class to be something of a singleton that once `Config.init()` is called and the class properties are setup, I have access to the properties from anywhere we import this class?

Comment: Of course it's `null` there. You didn't wait for it to resolve.

Comment: Have you considered `import config from '/app/config/config.json'` (or something like that)? That way it wouldn't be asynchronous.

Comment: Use flux with an appStore. Populate the appStore.appData with the config data. Trigger your top level component with the appData. Pass around as needed.

Comment: @JanakaStevens do you have any link to that kind of feature?

Comment: @Bergi I don't want it compiled, I'm tokenizing the data in that json file after the build server builds it. Its changed for every environment we deploy the build to.

Comment: @ShawnMclean: I see. Of course it depends on what kind of module loader or bundling you are using, but it might have been a simpler answer than you were looking for :-)

Comment: This project has a variety of patterns. https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns. Check out RefluxPages for an example of using an appStore. I don't have a router pattern yet, I like to use websockets. But the general pattern is there.